# Using web services to retrieve data from a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

Recently I have been developing a system to run a high secured database (using vb.net and SQL Server 2005). I want to increase the security of the database so no connection will be made directly to the database but instead a `HttpWebRequest` is sent to a web service which then connects to the database and returns the requested data table in XML format.

My concern is just about the performance, I can not decide either to let clients connect directly to the database or let the connection go through the web service.

I can make the connection go directly to the database for many reasons, let say that connection is through the service:

1. Will it give me a better performance?
2. Will the size of retrieved data will be larger than the regular response of the SQL Server?

Any ideas about this will help a lot, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Through the WebService, it will not give you a better performance, since it's adding a layer of code between your client and the database.

2) Since webservices use an envelope and a header, my best guess would be that the data is bigger.  Unless you have large sets of data, it shouldn't hurt your performance too much.

Nevertheless, I would still use a WebService, to avoid exposing my database directly to the internet, thus limiting security breaches.  Also, using a webservice allows you to write your security rules in it, and discard possible code injection and other security threats before it can reach your database.

Answer (score 0):

Using web service is a best choice but this need to be used wisely. You cannot just have a web service and start downloading data through it. A bad design/architecture may hit performance as well as security.

If you can share some more details about your scenario, i.e., number of clients that can connect to web service, frequency of connections, volume of data, then i can suggest you some architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. 
The project may have up to 15 users (at least 5 online at the same time) and the database may contain up to (2000) in one table and up to (20,000) in another table [this table will is a relational one so only up to 100 records are retried at the same time]

For each session up to 35 connections may be made to the web service.
Any suggestion about that?
Thanks in advanced

Comment: In this situation, a simple web service is enough.

But still I will suggest you to add some filters in web methods to restrict data. Below are some variations you can use:-

1. DownloadData(Record ID)
2. DownloadData(FromDateTime, ToDateTime)
3. DownloadData(LastSyncDateTime)

I hope this will help you to let clients access data without any performance issues.

Some additional things you can do is to use below:-

1. Use JSON. This will reduce size of data downloaded and help you to download more data in single request.

2. Make use of indexes on tables where you are fetching data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
The client software will retrieve data [request that] in many different ways, for instance, the search queries will contain many changeable condensations like {a record that it is between two dates and the field X doesn't contain 'string' AND field Y is larger than 7} and also it may have conditions related with other tables, What I am trying to say that on single request can contain many different parameters so do say that I should create a web method for each single query? 

And about Json, is supported in .net platform? How I can convert it to a dataset?

Comment: 1. Creating methods and parameters, purely depends on your business needs. It seems you have understood my point well. So try to keep the results returned from web service as small as possible. 
You can create a single method with many parameters to filter your data. This approach may make things complex and your cade may be difficult to debug.

I suggest you to write more methods each dealing with one or related set of parameters. This is the best and popular approach among developers.

2. .NET has libraries available to deal with JSON. e.g., JSON.NET

Comment: Oh thanks a lot it was really helpful. 
Can you please send me some links about JASON.NET?
Also, is it possible that we can be in touch in the future to discuss about this ongoing project?
Thanks,

Comment: Here are some links:-

https://json.codeplex.com/
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/samples.htm

Sure, feel free to drop me a message if you need some help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If satisfied, please mark my suggestions as answer :)

Comment: Sorry I have only 7 points, am I able to mark it as an answer?

Comment: No idea. I am also new to SO. Dont' worry. Leave it if you are unable. :)